# How to validate form with json fetch?

Tags: javascript, fetch

So I got this form, whenever I click send, it throws back response and error message at the same time.
Why is that happening? Even when the form is empty. It is supposed to add the `errorc` class when field is empty.
It all works fine, when I have `required` in html but I need to handle the error through error catch response.

```
const myForm = document.getElementById('contact-form');
  
  myForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(myForm);

    fetch('@/api/contact_form_messages', {
      method: 'post',
      body: formData
    })
    .then((checkStatus))
    .then((response) => {
      document.getElementById("success-msg").innerHTML = "Message has been sent.";
      myForm.reset();
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((error) => { 
     document.getElementById("warning-msg").innerHTML = "Message not sent";
     for(errors in error) {
      myForm.elements[errorKey].classList.add('errorc');
     }

    })

    function checkStatus (response) {
      if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        return response
      }
      else if (response.status == 422) {
      document.getElementById("warning-msg").innerHTML = "Message not sent.";
      }
      else {
        var error = new Error(response.statusText)
        error.response = response
        throw error
      }
    }  
   
  });
```

console.log(error);

```
undefined
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "throws back response and error message"?

Comment: I get response success and then innerHTML text says message has been sent, and under that it says it has not sent. It throws back response and error at same time.

Comment: If you are getting a `422` response code it looks like your code will not throw an error, and you will get both messages added to the DOM, and the `error` object will be undefined. Is that what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

1. It looks like your `checkStatus` function is incorrect. Try this instead:

```
    function checkStatus (response) {
      if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        return response
      }
      else { 
        // Now any response code > 299 should add your HTML message *and* throw an error.
        document.getElementById("warning-msg").innerHTML = "Message not sent.";
   
        var error = new Error(response.statusText)
        error.response = response
        throw error
      }
    }
```

2. Why are you iterating over `error`, and what is `errorKey` supposed to be?
   Looks to me like your catch handler should look more like:

```
    .catch((error) => { 
     document.getElementById("warning-msg").innerHTML = "Message not sent";
     
     // assuming `errorKey` is defined and in scope
     // error will be your Error object that you throw in `checkStatus`.
     // Unless an object has iterable keys (eg `{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }` you will not be able to use `for in` on it
     myForm.elements[errorKey].classList.add('errorc');

    })
```

Comment: I've removed the ==422 response. It's fine now. The thing that is not working properly is the for statement in catch(error). It doesn't add a class at all, when there is error in input field. My api is in json format and it has required "Can't be blank"

Comment: What is `errorKey` and is it defined in scope? Try to `console.log` it where your code is failing

Comment: .catch((error won't work if you don't define error under.

Comment: All I need now, is to handle the error that json returns. If field is empty. Json returns "Can't be blank". Whenever that happens. I want the class errorc to be added to input. Thats why I tried for loop for this.